# get id of clicked element but get wrong target

Tags: jquery

I need to get the id of the button used to submit a form (with jquery ajax).
Here is a form with class "blog-form":

```
<form method="post" class="blog-form" action="/blog/post"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Here is button used to submit the form with ajax/jquery. The goal is to get "uploador" id value

```
 <button id="uploador" type="submit"> Upload an image</button>
```

Here is the jquery:

```
 $( '.blog-form' ).on( 'submit', function( e ) {
            e.preventDefault();
            console.log(e);
           //rest of code
```

i can't find a way to get the id of the clicked button 'uploador' in the 'e' event. Target shows form, not button.
Where to look ? Looked at many post but most asked to look at target which is not a solution in this case.

Comment: You can't use `$('#uploador')`?

Comment: for some reason it will corrupt the ajax submission process and won't producce the desired effect but this is another story.

Comment: $(#uploador).on('click',e=>{

})

do this for all your buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you might want to use a global js variable:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var pushedButtonId = false;
</script>
```

And further below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#uploador').on('click', function() {
        pushedButtonId = $(this).attr('id');
    });
    $('.blog-form').on('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(e);
        if (pushedButtonId === false) {
            return; // The form wasn't submitted by hittig the button 
        }
        //pushedButtonId variable has the button id
        //rest of code
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Define name attribute to your button to get form element.Then use `document.getAttribute()` to get id of button.

HTML

```
<form method="post" class="blog-form" action="#t"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <button id="uploador" type="submit" name="upload"> Upload an image</button>
 </form>
```

JS

```
var form =  document.querySelector(".blog-form");
 form.addEventListener('submit',function(){
 var btn =this.elements["upload"];
 //console.log(btn);
alert(btn.getAttribute('id'));
 });
```

[See Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Hek_Mat/tzcwz8v3/)

Answer (score 1):

You can get the ID of the button retrieving it from the form that you get in the event.

```
$( '.blog-form' ).on( 'submit', function( e ) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert($(e.target).children("button[type='submit']").attr("id"));
});
```